# Compiled with problems. in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, tailwind-css

ERROR in ./node_modules/loaders.css/loaders.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[2]!./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/loaders.css/loaders.css)

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: Cannot find module 'daisyui'
Require stack:

- F:\VS code\three js\material tailwind\Clone\FriendsZone\tailwind.config.js
- F:\VS code\three js\material tailwind\Clone\FriendsZone\node_modules\tailwindcss\lib\lib\setupTrackingContext.js
- F:\VS code\three js\material tailwind\Clone\FriendsZone\node_modules\tailwindcss\lib\index.js
- F:\VS code\three js\material tailwind\Clone\FriendsZone\node_modules\postcss-loader\dist\utils.js
- F:\VS code\three js\material tailwind\Clone\FriendsZone\node_modules\postcss-loader\dist\index.js
- F:\VS code\three js\material tailwind\Clone\FriendsZone\node_modules\postcss-loader\dist\cjs.js
- F:\VS code\three js\material tailwind\Clone\FriendsZone\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js
- F:\VS code\three js\material tailwind\Clone\FriendsZone\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js
- F:\VS code\three js\material tailwind\Clone\FriendsZone\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js
- F:\VS code\three js\material tailwind\Clone\FriendsZone\node_modules\webpack-manifest-plugin\dist\index.js
- F:\VS code\three js\material tailwind\Clone\FriendsZone\node_modules\react-scripts\config\webpack.config.js
- F:\VS code\three js\material tailwind\Clone\FriendsZone\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
  at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
  at Object. (F:\VS code\three js\material tailwind\Clone\FriendsZone\tailwind.config.js:46:13)
  at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
  at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19

**Any one help me, Thanks in Advance.**

Comment: It's hard to say what's going on with just this, but it appears that you're missing a package. Try re-installing a package (looks like you're missing tailwind?). If that doesn't work trying using a forced installation (npm install <package> --f).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try to check files which are actually written by you, modern ide can highlight places with errors. Try double checking the steps by which you have installed tailwind. Without source code hard to help

Answer (score 0):

Removing the entire **node_modules** folder and re-installing:

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but  this method I have already use, but problem was still exists.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).